# Module returning before all inputs have updated

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shinymodules

I currently have a module that has three user inputs, which dynamically update depending on a dataset so people can't choose options that don't exist. These inputs then get taken to the main server for use in graphs/tables etc.

My problem is that server.R is receiving updates when inputs are changed too quickly and it's not waiting for all the inputs to update (since choice 3 depends on choice 2 and choice 2 depends on choice 1).

My initial options are:

"Choice 1:" "1"
"Choice 2:" "a"
"Choice 3:" "A ONLY 1"

If i change choice 2 to "b" I get the following in console:

"Choice 1:" "1"
"Choice 2:" "b"
"Choice 3:" "A ONLY 1"

"Choice 1:" "1"
"Choice 2:" "b"
"Choice 3:" "B ONLY 1"

Choice 3 hasn't updated quickly enough which will cause errors throughout my. Any idea how I can get the user_inputs in server.R to wait for all choices to finished updating?

Example code:

```
    test_data <- data.frame(matrix(c(
      1,"a","A ONLY 1",
      1,"a","A ONLY 1",
      1,"b","B ONLY 1",
      1,"b","B ONLY 2",
      2,"d","D ONLY 1"),byrow = TRUE,ncol = 3))
    names(test_data) <- c("choice1","choice2","choice3")
    
    
    module_inputs_ui <- function(id) {
      ns <- NS(id)
      
      shiny::fluidPage(  
            shiny::selectizeInput(
              label = "1",
              inputId = ns("choose1"),
              choices = c(1,2)
              ),
            selectInput(
              label = "2",
              inputId = ns("choose2"),
              choices = c("a","b")
              ),
            selectInput(
              label = "3",
              inputId = ns("choose3"),
              choices = c("x","y")
            )
      )
      
    }
    
    
    
    module_inputs_server <- function(id) {
      
      moduleServer(id, 
                   function(input, output, session) {
     
                     choice_2_new <- reactive({
                       test_data %>%
                         filter(choice1 == input$choose1) %>%
                         pull(choice2) %>%
                         unique()
                     })
                     
    
                     choice_3_new <- reactive({
                       test_data %>%
                         filter(choice1 == input$choose1) %>%
                         filter(choice2 == input$choose2) %>%
                         pull(choice3) %>%
                         unique()
                     })
                     
                     observeEvent(input$choose1, {
                       
                       updateSelectInput(
                         session = session,
                         inputId = "choose2",
                         choices = choice_2_new()
                       ) 
    
                       
                     })   
                     
                     
                     observeEvent(input$choose2, {
       
                       
                       updateSelectInput(
                         session = session,
                         inputId = "choose3",
                         choices = choice_3_new()
                       ) 
                       
                       
                     })   
                     # Return List -------------------------------------------------------------
    
                     return(
                       list(
                         out1 = reactive({input$choose1}),
                         out2 = reactive({input$choose2}),
                         out3 = reactive({input$choose3})
                       )
                       )
    
                   })
      
    }
    
    ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
      module_inputs_ui(id = "module_1")
    )
    
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      user_inputs <- module_inputs_server(id = "module_1")  
    
      # # Printing inputs from user (for debuggins etc.)
      observe({
        
        print(c("Choice 1:", user_inputs$out1()))
        
        print(c("Choice 2:", user_inputs$out2()))
        
        print(c("Choice 3:", user_inputs$out3()))
    
        
      })
      
    }
    
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the second observer depends on `choice_3_new`, you should observe on that. Then it works fine. Try this

```
test_data <- data.frame(matrix(c(
  1,"a","A ONLY 1",
  2,"a","A ONLY 2",
  1,"b","B ONLY 1",
  2,"b","B ONLY 2",
  2,"d","D ONLY 1"),byrow = TRUE,ncol = 3))
names(test_data) <- c("choice1","choice2","choice3")

module_inputs_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  shiny::fluidPage(  
    shiny::selectizeInput(
      label = "1",
      inputId = ns("choose1"),
      choices = c(1,2)
    ),
    selectInput(
      label = "2",
      inputId = ns("choose2"),
      choices = c("a","b")
    ),
    selectInput(
      label = "3",
      inputId = ns("choose3"),
      choices = c("x","y")
    )
  )
  
}

module_inputs_server <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, 
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 choice_2_new <- reactive({
                   test_data %>%
                     filter(choice1 == input$choose1) %>%
                     pull(choice2) %>%
                     unique()
                 })
                 
                 
                 choice_3_new <- reactive({
                   test_data %>%
                     filter(choice1 == input$choose1) %>%
                     filter(choice2 == input$choose2) %>%
                     pull(choice3) %>%
                     unique()
                 })
                 
                 observeEvent(input$choose1, {
                   req(choice_2_new())
                   updateSelectInput(
                     session = session,
                     inputId = "choose2",
                     choices = choice_2_new()
                   ) 
                 })   
                 
                 
                 observeEvent(choice_3_new(), {
                   updateSelectInput(
                     session = session,
                     inputId = "choose3",
                     choices = choice_3_new()
                   ) 
                 })   
                 # Return List -------------------------------------------------------------
                 
                 return(
                   list(
                     out1 = reactive({input$choose1}),
                     out2 = reactive({input$choose2}),
                     out3 = reactive({input$choose3})
                   )
                 )
                 
               })
  
}

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  module_inputs_ui(id = "module_1")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  user_inputs <- module_inputs_server(id = "module_1")  
  
  # # Printing inputs from user (for debuggins etc.)
  observe({
    
    print(c("Choice 1:", user_inputs$out1()))
    
    print(c("Choice 2:", user_inputs$out2()))
    
    print(c("Choice 3:", user_inputs$out3()))
    
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You beat me to it!  Alternatively, replace the `observe({` in the main server with `observeEvent(user_inputs$out3(), {`...

Comment: I still get in the console: "Choice 2:" "b"  "Choice 3:" "A ONLY 1"  when I change choice 2.

Comment: @Limey, yes, that does work for the observe but what's not shown is that user_inputs is still updating with incorrect choice2 / choice 3 combinations which would lead to incorrect tables/graphs ive stripped out of the example. That observe is there just to show whats happening/debugging.

Comment: Please use the `test_data` object in my answer.  It works fine for me.

Comment: I copied the whole thing. If you run it, and change Choice 2 to b, then the console will print 

1] "Choice 1:" "1"        
[1] "Choice 2:" "b"        
[1] "Choice 3:" "A ONLY 1" 

[1] "Choice 1:" "1"        
[1] "Choice 2:" "b"        
[1] "Choice 3:" "B ONLY 1" 

So choice 2 - b, and choice 3 - A ONLY 1 is being called by the server and so would error other things.

Comment: OP: you can hardly expect us to take account of the side effects of solutions we suggest in parts of your code *that you don't show us*!  As well as being minimal and reproducible, your example should be comprehensive.  Are you saying that you want *all* elements of your UI to update only when `out3` updates?  If so, add a reference to `out3` to every reactive and wrap all references to `out1` and `out2` in calls to `isolate`.  It seems to me that the fundamental thing you're asking for is "non-reactive reactives", which is something of an oxymoron, IMHO.

Comment: I'll try what you said Limey, but my opening sentence of the problem did describe the issue of the side effects quite plainly. 

It was comprehensive. Make the observe react as described, not change the observe.

Comment: I'm saying, I  don't want the main server 'user_inputs' to update, UNTIL all of the UI elements have finished updating. As in my OP, I currently get combos of Choice 2 b and Choice 3 'A ONLY' being sent to server together.

Comment: An alternative to `isolate`: make `out1` and `out2` non-reactive.  Still add references to `out3()` to every element you want to update.  Also consider using `session$userData` to transfer information, both static and reactive.  Since we disagree on the definition of "comprehensive", I shall refrain from further comment.